# how to remove all comments from a xml file least the ones containing the "HELP" word?

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to know the xml matching code to let me clean a file of all comments least the ones containing the HELP word.

I am currently using perl to clean multiline comments (like failed tests) from a xml, least the ones I hand picked and are helpful to the end user:
`perl -i -w -0777pe 's/<!--(.(?<!(HELP|TODO)))*?-->//sg' somefile.xml`

But, If there is a way to obtain the same result using a xml mathing string, I would prefer as there may have some exception that regex may not handle, but for now this is what I have to use.

Obs.: I will use it with xmlstarlet on linux, so it would be better if the solution work with it too.

Comment: You can try XSLT for the task.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, software library or other off-site resource are off-topic here according to the [help/on-topic] guidelines.

Comment: thx, I will try to save the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is XSLT based solution.

The XSLT is very simple. One single line template removes not needed comments. The rest is just a boilerplate code for a so called *Identity Transform* pattern.

```
$ xml tr path/to/transformation.xslt path/to/source.xml
```

**Input XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <!--The Sunshine State-->
    <state>FL</state>
    <!--HELP is needed-->
    <city>Miami</city>
</root>
```

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--keeps comment if it contains HELP-->
    <xsl:template match="comment()[not(contains(., 'HELP'))]" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**xmlstarlet**
`xmlstarlet ed -d '//comment()[not(contains(.,"HELP"))]' path/to/source.xml`

**Output**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
<root>
  <state>FL</state>
  <!--HELP is needed-->
  <city>Miami</city>
</root>
```

Comment: thank you!! I didnt know how to prepare the matching code. now xmlstartlet is working like: `xmlstarlet ed -d '//comment()[not(contains(.,"HELP"))]' myfile.xml`, the idea is to keep only comments with the HELP word. I will try to save the question too.

Comment: Glad to hear that the proposed solution steered you into a right direction.

Comment: I tested the xslt code with xmlstarlet and it worked too. I will invert the match to accept this, thx!